# jQuery doesn't work in input field

Tags: jquery, html

i want to save values in to db where we calculate called total and grand total.so i want to calculate it in the input field.i have tried that.but doesn't work. 
as i realize the issues come with `$('.multTotal',this).text(total);` "text" in the line and `$("#grandTotal").text(mult);` and "text" in the line .
can u help me plz

**View**

```
    <table class="table" id="boq_tbl">
        <thead>

       <thead>

            <tbody>
    <tr class="txtMult">

                <td><input type="text" name="work_product_id" class="form-control" id="work_product_id" placeholder=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cost_code" class="form-control" id="cost_code" placeholder=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="work_item_description" class="form-control" id="work_item_description" placeholder=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="quentity" id="" class="form-control val1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="unit" class="form-control val2"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="laboure_hrs" id="" class="form-control val3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text"name="laboure_cost" id="" class="form-control val4"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="others" class="form-control" id="others" placeholder=""></td>


        <td>
                <span class="multTotal">0.00</span>
        </td>
    </tr>

     </tbody>
       </table> 
<p align="right">
    Grand Total# <span id="grandTotal">0.00</span>
</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
 <script>
$("#insert-more").click(function () {
     $("#boq_tbl").each(function () {
         var tds = '<tr class="txtMult">';
         jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
             tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
         });
         tds += '</tr>';
         if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
             $('tbody', this).append(tds);
         } else {
             $(this).append(tds);
         }
     });
});

$("#boq_tbl").on("keyup", ".txtMult input", multInputs);


function multInputs() {
    var mult = 0;
    // for each row:
    $("tr.txtMult").each(function () {

        console.log('---dkhal');
        // get the values from this row:
        var val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
        var val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
        var val3 = $('.val3', this).val();
        var val4 = $('.val4', this).val();
        var total = (val1 * val2 ) + (val3 * val4);

        console.log('---'+val1 * val2);
        $('.multTotal',this).text(total);
        mult += total;
    });
    $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
}


</script>
```

Comment: shouldn't you parse the values before doing additions and multiplications?

Comment: Please try my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
function multInputs() {
    var mult = 0;
    $("tr.txtMult").each(function () {
        var val1 = $('#val1', this).val();
        var val2 = $('#val2', this).val();
        var val3 = $('#val3', this).val();
        var val4 = $('#val4', this).val();
        var total = (parseInt(val1) * parseInt(val2) ) + (parseInt(val3) * parseInt(val4));
        $('.multTotal',this).text(total);
        mult += total;
        $('#txtmultTotal').val(mult);
    });
    $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
    $('#txtgrandTotal').val(mult);
}
```

**Problems in your code:**

```
`val1,va12,val3,val4`
```

are not class ,its Id's. So you should write like `$('#val1', this).val();` not like `$('.val1', this).val();`.

You should use [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp) to convert the value to integer.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bcdo7muo/13/)

Comment: the issue is it doesn't work when i add total values as input field

Comment: @ashik did you check my demo?

Comment: yes.my code also work.plese help me add the calculation into input field

Comment: @ashik " add the calculation into input field " means?

Comment: <td><span class="multTotal">0.00</span> </td> this is the place which caluculate the total.i want show it input field.because i want to save it data base.
<td><input type="text"  class="multTotal"></td>

Comment: @ashik I have updated the code... Please verify... https://jsfiddle.net/bcdo7muo/7/

Comment: thanx @rino it's work. but i want to get both grand total and total in to input field.
total is the total which is show the calculated result for the one row
grand total is the total value for the total row.

Comment: no @rino. that is not actually what i want.when i add new row total column doesn't work fine

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the issues with this code is using . instead of # throughout. For example,

```
  var val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
```

should read

```
  var val1 = $('#val1', this).val();
```

and there are many other examples. "." is for class and "#" is for id.

Comment: Why not simple `$('#val1').val()`? as Ids must be unique

Comment: this code is working fine.but the issue is when i insert it in input field as ex:
 <td><input type="text" class="multTotal"></td> instead of this code<td><span class="multTotal">0.00</span></td> it doesn't work

Comment: How is it working? You don't have the correct selectors

Answer (score 0):

As described above change your 'class' names to 'id' specific and also call the :

```js
 $("#boq_tbl").on("keyup", ".txtMult input", multInputs);
```

method after the DOM is ready like

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#boq_tbl").on( "keyup" , ".txtMult input" , multInputs );
});
```